# Polymer serve and service worker

Tags: polymer, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, polymer-cli

I am trying to get started on debugging my Polymer application.  I have hand crafted it by copying what I think the `PolymerCLI` `Polymer init` does.

I am not sure what is loading service worker.  The default one for development just does a `console.info()` call saying its been disabled for development.

When I use `Polymer serve` to serve my application on localhost: 8080, I get the console.info message, despite there being nowhere where I actually load the file `service-worker.js` .  Because the application is much more complex (and I am trying to use http/2) I have my own node based server as well.  When I run that and then fetch my application in the browser, service-worker.js does not get loaded and run.

What is `Polymer serve` doing to enable it?

Comment: Which `polymer init` template are you using? E.g. `polymer init application`, `polymer init app-drawer-template`, etc.

Comment: I hand crafted the app since it existed before polymer cli was created.  I created a standard application in an alternative directory and copied the appropriate files (service-worker.js, sw-precache-config.js) and used the rest of the files as guides to edit what I already had.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that a different application which used the same source (e.g. `localhost:8080`) registered and installed a service worker.

Open up the Application panel in Chrome Canary to inspect / delete the service worker.

[image]

If you can't access Chrome Canary, open `chrome://serviceworker-internals`, find the scope that matches your app, and click **Unregister**. There's also an option at the top of `serviceworker-internals` which lets you open a DevTools window and pause JS on the SW. Enable that option and you'll be able to see which SW is running.

Comment: This is probably it, although I am not sure how to check because I haven't got canary installed (I am running Debian).  I created a dummy app with polymer init just to see what it would do.  I also created a copy of to google shop application to look at that.  One of those might have done that, but why does console log respond what is in my `/service-worker.js`

Comment: @akc42 check out the workflow at the bottom of my edited answer

Comment: Thanks.  I "think" I get it now.  It appears that the code in the dummy app registered the url `/service-worker.js` when it was located at localhost:8080.  This service worker code is identical to the code in my app because I just copied it so it is impossible to say which version is being used.  The only puzzle I have now is that I thought service workers are https only, and this was is being activated on localhost http connection.

Comment: @akc42 you are mostly correct that service workers must run over HTTPS, but `localhost` is one of the few exceptions. The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#security-considerations) says "Devtools can loosen the [security] restriction for development (file://, localhost, etc.)".