# Register deleted service worker

Tags: service-worker, polymer-2.x

Hey I am really struggeling with polymer 2.x after `polymer init` my sw did not work so I decided to unregister it from

> chrome://serviceworker-internals/

following to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727052/polymer-serve-and-service-worker) after that all I get is this:

[image: sw]

How can I enable the service worker again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code in your application, after first render or whenever you want, to register the service worker:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
}
```

If supported this code will register the service worker.

If you want to add in `index.html`:

```
<script>
      const baseUrl = document.querySelector('base').href;

      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register(baseUrl + 'service-worker.js');
        });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I work with polymer 2.0 so the sw will be generated by build?

Comment: So refreshing your page will load sw again.